# Prediction interval of the future median based on a series of future samples

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, bootstrap, simulation

I am using R and have based my analysis on the book by *Hyndman, R.J., & Athanasopoulos, G. (2021) Forecasting: principles and practice, 3rd edition, OTexts* using the *fpp3* package (https://otexts.com/fpp3/)

The aim is to estimate number of averted cases after the implementation of an intervention. I have fitted an Arima model to the following time series of yearly incidence data which after log-transformation is stationary based on KPSS test (function unitroot_kpss). Using the ARIMA function from the same package for automatically deciding on the best model based on AICc (using also stepwise=FALSE for a more extensive search) i get the model Arima(5,0,0) as the most fitting. A residual check shows that there is no residual autocorrelation left, the Ljung-Box test also verifies that the residuals are white noise.

As it can be seen in the graph, the prediction intervals of the median yearly incidence are simply too wide making it pointless to estimate uncertainty around the predicted averted cases. The intervals are of course the same also for the mean. What i have considered and would like a second opinion is to estimate the median incidence for the whole post-intervention period, instead by year, and use the prediction interval around that to estimate uncertainty around the averted cases. In this way we do lose the yearly predictions but i can't think of an alternative when they are as non-informative as in this case.

I have done this by simulating 10000 future paths from the fitted Arima(5,0,0) model using bootstrap residuals, estimating the median incidence for whole the post-intervention period for each of them and finally the median of all medians in the following way:

```
futures <- arima500 |>
   generate(times = 10000, h = 49, set.seed(123),bootstrap = TRUE,
   point_forecast = list(.median = median)) |> 
   as_tibble() |>
   group_by(.rep) |>
   summarise(.sim = median(.sim)) |>
   summarise(total = distributional::dist_sample(list(.sim)))

  future_median <- futures |>
   mutate(
    median = median(total),
    pi80 = hilo(total, 80),
    pi95 = hilo(total, 95)
   )
```

Inspiration for this came from the section *"Prediction intervals from bootstrapped residuals"* in (https://otexts.com/fpp3/prediction-intervals.html)
and (https://otexts.com/fpp3/aggregates.html) where the setup in that example was to aggregate monthly data to get yearly estimates.

My questions are:

1. Is this approach statistically correct?
2. If so, is it more correct to estimate the median of medians (median = median(total) in the code above) or the mean of medians instead? Is it simply a matter of choice?
3. I haven't worked a lot with arima models and the order of the chosen model (5th order autoregressive model) was a bit surprising. I am more used to seeing lower order models. Is there something to be considered there? Models selected by the ARIMA function will not contain roots outside or close to the unit circle so that part is already taken care of.
4. Finally, how well are Arima models suited for long forecasting as in this case. Should other models be preferred instead?

[image]

Comment: There seem to be pronounced cycles in your time series, of unequal length. `ARIMA` is picking up on these, which gives you the AR(5) component - and it would probably go much higher than that if it were allowed to, try fiddling around with the maximum AR order via the `order_constraint` parameter. It seems like the very first order of business would be to understand where these cycles come from and whether they can be modeled and predicted.

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand what you mean by "prediction interval of the median". PIs refer to observed outcomes, not to summary statistics. Unless, that is, your base time series is already a summary and contains medians of something.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Stephan. I have tried higher orders of the AR term but the AR(5) is still suggested as the one with lowest AICc. The data come from an infectious disease which has a periodicity in outbreaks as it can be seen. The data are yearly though so i can't apply a SARIMA model and the fitted values of the arima(5,0,0) model follow the time series in general well.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, i wasn't totally clear. There is no aggregation, this is the actual data. What i meant is that the blue line in the graph is the backtransformed (due to log transformation) bias unadjusted estimate, so each point prediction is the median of the forecasted distribution for that point, as shown here: https://otexts.com/fpp3/ftransformations.html

Comment: If your process is driven by underlying forces with cyclicity, then ARIMA is not the right tool, and you see that in the humongous prediction intervals. Better to do a regression on underlying predictors, or try to decompose the series to get at that underlying cyclicity. Yes, that will make detecting any influence of a treatment harder, especially since it's quite possible the treatment only affects the very peaks.

Comment: There are no really good regressors, that is the problem. One could do a poisson regression in an interrupted time series setup with a time trend and sin-cos terms and extrapolate the trend in the post-intervention period. You probably have an STL in mind instead? What do you think of my suggestion of using simulated future samples to estimate the mean/median of the whole period instead of the point estimates? It reduces the uncertainty of that estimate to levels that can be used to estimate the uncertainty around the averted cases.

Comment: To be honest, I think that any model that does not account for these rather blatant cycles in *some* way (even if only in a very ad-hoc manner, e.g., using trigonometric dummies) is so far off that the question of whether to sample or not is still not very relevant...

Comment: The Arima(5,0,0) does take care of this cyclicity though, the fitted values of the model follow to a large extent nicely the observed time series.

Comment: When I look at the median forecasts, they get dampened to a long-run average by 1990. That may indeed be the best we can do if the cycle lengths are really so very hard to predict and vary a lot. They just seem so regular to me that I would try predicting them better before I trust this ARIMA model.